# HttpClient ReadAsByteArrayAsync vs ReadAsStreamAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

In HttpClient we have some methods to read response content. I am interesting in difference between ReadAsByteArrayAsync vs ReadAsStreamAsync. Is there any difference between them? Or is ReadAsStreamAsync just wrapper which allowes pass bytes to methods that needs Stream abstraction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs) the [ByteArray](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1dc2ab40ea78bbd78f522a13272462e1b866d951/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs#L236) method will read the entire stream into a new `byte[]` copy for you.

```
// The returned array is exposed out of the library, so use ToArray rather
// than TryGetBuffer in order to make a copy.
```

Whereas Stream will just return you the stream to do what you want with it (the opposite of what you suggested).

If you have a usecase for processing the entire response as bytes, then ByteArray might help you, if you need to work with a stream, use the Stream.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do I understand correctly: if I will be use ReadAsStreamAsync() I can start processing the response, even if it is not yet fully loaded into the internal buffer?

Answer (score 0):

**ReadAsByteArrayAsync()**：

Serialize the HTTP content to a byte array as an asynchronous operation.

This operation will not block. The returned [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-5.0) object will complete after all of the content has been written as a byte array.

Once the operation completes, the [Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-5.0) property on the returned task object contains the byte array with the HTTP content.

**ReadAsStreamAsync()**：

Serialize the HTTP content and return a stream that represents the content as an asynchronous operation.

This operation will not block. The returned [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-5.0) object will complete after all of the stream that represents content has been read.

Once the operation completes, the [Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-5.0) property on the returned task object contains the stream that represents the HTTP content. The returned stream can then be used to read the content using various stream APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do I understand correctly: with performance point of view it doesn't matter what method is using because both of them wait until all response will be load into inner buffer? And which method to choose depends on which API will use the http response somewhere further?